# Batch file to parse text file for string that will execute SQL statement on returning true

Tags: sql-server, powershell, parsing, batch-file, scripting

I'm working on setting up a batch file to parse through a log file for a certain string of words: "more than one matching element". This string of words is in a sentence in a log file when an issue is occurring on my server. I know java, but I don't really know DOS, so I'm kind of winging it.  Anyways, when if the batch script parses through the file, and finds this string of words, I think I can use an IF statement to execute a SQL statement in SQL SERVER through command prompt to fix the issue.

That being said, I'm running into a problem. When testing I run into an error: in() was unexpected at this time. I believe it's due to my file not being recognized possibly, and the parsing hasn't begun yet? I have multiple files in this folder, with the same name. Those files have dates after the name that is in the filepath of my batch script, like this : 'JobRunnerLogFile.winservice020619.txt' The current log file for today has the exact name from my filepath below. Is it possible that the batch script look at the exact name, or just what the file begins with? Does it not know which file to open? Also is my syntax below to parse through the file for that string of text correct?

```
@echo off
set %file% = "H:\Program Files (x86)\Test\JobRunnerLogFile.winservice.txt"
for /f "tokens=more than one matching element" %%A in(%file%)                      
do(echo%%A)
pause
cmd /k
```

Comment: Like this? "H:\Program Files (x86)\Test\JobRunnerLogFile.winservice.txt" also, does set %file% need to be set file = ?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server and Windows already, would it be better to look at a Powershell option?

Comment: I guess it could, I just know many of the scheduled tasks on our server run .bat files right now, so I just figured I'd go with the same. Also, I've edited a few .bat files here and there so it felt a bit familiar I guess.

Comment: I was pretty much just throwing out another option. I'd go with what's in use in your system and what you're comfortable with. For the most part, Powershell is basically Batch on lots of steroids, but that may be a bit much for what you're trying to do here. :-)  (And TBH, I've probably written much more Batch code to do non-complex things than PS)

Comment: Pretty much the only syntax you got correct was `@echo off` and `pause`. The rest of your code looks like you didn't read the help files for the commands you are trying to use. You can read the help for a command by opening a cmd prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. `set /?` or `for /?`. The `TOKENS` options definitely doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Regardless of what I said in my previous comment I think all you really want to do is search a file for a string.  The easiest way to do that would be to use the `FIND` or `FINDSTR` commands.  If the the string is found you could use conditional execution to execute another command. You could also use an `IF` command to check the errorlevel of the `FINDSTR` command to do something as well.

Comment: I actually recommend you learn powershell. Normally I recommend remaining consistent with what you have, but Powershell is light years ahead of batch (error handling, access to .Net classes), and if you ever need to work somewhere else, it's likely they will also user powershell.

Comment: Wrong [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) syntax, wrong [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) syntax; seems you were guessing rather than reading the help texts that appear when typing a command plus `/?` into a Command Prompt window... or have you retyped the code instead of copying it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not have understood your question 100% as it is a little unclear, but if I did, you're looking for something like this:

```
@echo off
set "file=H:\Program Files (x86)\Test\JobRunnerLogFile.winservice.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in('type %file% ^| findstr /i "more than one matching element"') do (
   echo some cmd here
   echo %%a
 )
 pause
```

We `type` through the file and search for the string using `findstr`.

you can get more help on the commands by getting to their help page on `cmd` by doing:

```
for /?
set /?
findstr /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task isn't very clear, this will hopefully get you a little bit closer to your intention.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SD=H:\Program Files (x86)\Test"
Set "SF=JobRunnerLogFile.winservice*.txt"
Set "SS=more than one matching element"
If Not Exist "%SD%\%SF%" Exit /B
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /IMC:"%SS%" "%SD%\%SF%"'
) Do Echo String match found in "%%~nxA"
Pause
```

*You would obviously replace the `Echo` command with your `SQL` command/statement.*

*If you needed the full filename, change `"%%~nxA"` to `"%%A"`*

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly try this.

This searches for multiple unique strings in any .txt log file located on your Desktop. If any found it triggers a SQLstatementSQL.bat file which should contain your SQL statement in SQL SERVER through command prompt to fix the issue.

If the log files didn't contain those strings it will echo LOGFILEISOKAY.

Save this as a .bat file and change the paths to match yours. Hope it helps.

The /S switch on findstr searches all files in a directory. If you know the specific name of the file you can change this bat file to reflect that. Something like:

```
findstr "more than one matching element" "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\IKNOWTHEFILENAME.txt"
```

Here is the .bat file.

```
:: each word you are looking for seperated by a whitespace.

@echo off   
findstr /S "more than one matching element" "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\*.txt"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
call "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\SQLstatementSQL.bat"
goto done
:notfound
echo LOGFILEISOKAY
goto done
:done
```